# useRef not working [TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'filed2.current.focus')]

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ref, use-ref

I'm trying to focus on the next input field whenever the next button is pressed on the keyboard.

From the react native documentation I've understood that we need to use the useRef hook. However following the document

`TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'filed2.current.focus')`

I'm using the latest version of all packages, with a new react native app with the typescript template.

here is the bit of code that I have so far:

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react';

...

  const filed1 = useRef(null);
  const filed2 = useRef(null);

  const onButtonClick = () => {
    filed2.current.focus();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <FormInputPassword
        ref={filed1}
        returnKeyType="next"
        onSubmitEditing={onButtonClick}
        blurOnSubmit={false}
      />
      <FormInputPassword
        ref={filed2}
        returnKeyType="done"
        blurOnSubmit={false}
      />
    </ >
  );
```

Edit:

```
function FormInputPassword(props) {
  return (
      <FormInputView>
        <Input {...props} />
      </FormInputView>
  );
}


FormInputPassword.defaultProps = {
  blurOnSubmit: true,
  autoCorrect: false,
  editable: true,
};
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `import React, {useRef} from 'react';`?

Comment: `filed2.current` maybe null. Use optional chaining: `filed2.current?.focus();` Also, your need to use parameterized type `const filed2 = useRef< FormInputPassword>(null);`
or whatever suitable type is

Comment: @Nishant that gives me `Property 'focus' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)`

Comment: Can you include the definition of `FormInputPassword`? My guess is that you're not forwarding the `ref` that it receives to a DOM node

Comment: @Dancrumb I've added it to the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function components can't have ref instance.

- [`React.forwardRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactforwardref).
- [Can I make a ref to a function component?](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#can-i-make-a-ref-to-a-function-component)

```
React.forwardRef((props,ref) => {
  return (
      <FormInputView ref={ref}>
        <Input {...props} />
      </FormInputView>
  );
});
```

Comment: The same will probably need to be done for `FormInputView`, (or the `ref` should be set directly on the `<Input>`)

Answer (score 0):

If `FormInputPassword` is a functional component, then you need to wrap it with `[forwardRef][1]`.

Functional components don't take refs by default, so you need to wrap it and then forward the ref to a DOM component or a class component inside your component.