# why got null is not an object when app move to another screen in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I created an auto scroll flatlist for the home screen. When the user logout, it would direct the user to the login screen. The problem is that I got `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'ref.current.scrollToIndex')` when the app direct the user to the login screen. What happen and how do I resolve it?

Auto scroll flatlist component:

```js
export const BannerCarousel = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    let index = 0;
    const totalIndex = props.data.length ;
    useEffect (() => { 
        setInterval (() => {
            index = index + 1;
            if(index < totalIndex) {
                ref.current.scrollToIndex({animated: true, index: index})
            } else {
                ref.current.scrollToIndex({animated: true, index: 0})
                index = 0;
            }
        }, 3000)
    }, []);
    
    return (
        <View style={{paddingHorizontal: 10}} >
            <FlatList 
                ref={ref}
                data={props.data} 
                keyExtractor={data => data.id}
                renderItem={renderItem}
            /> 
        </View>
    );
});
```

Home.js

```js
    const ref = React.createRef() 
    return (
      <BannerCarousel fromLocal={true} data={TopBannerData} ref={ref}/>
    );
```

Comment: Can you share the code where you are redirecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the error occurs because the BannerCarousal component is trying to find the `ref.current`. The `ref.current` is gone when the user is redirected to the Login screen. That's why the error `null is not an object` occurs. This is the solution that I did:

```js
export const BannerCarousel = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    let index = 0;
    const totalIndex = props.data.length ;
    useEffect (() => { 
        setInterval (() => {
            if(ref.current !== null) {
              index = index + 1;
              if(index < totalIndex) {
                  ref.current.scrollToIndex({animated: true, index: index})
              } else {
                  ref.current.scrollToIndex({animated: true, index: 0})
                  index = 0;
              } 
            }
            
        }, 3000)
    }, []);
    
    return (
        <View style={{paddingHorizontal: 10}} >
            <FlatList 
                ref={ref}
                data={props.data} 
                keyExtractor={data => data.id}
                renderItem={renderItem}
            /> 
        </View>
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Where you are referencing the useRef flatListRef  ?   it seems like its not referencing any Valid Node.  So it returns..

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'flatListRef.current.scrollToIndex')
```

Comment: yes its referencing the flatlist. I updated the post

Comment: Try removing null in the useRef while intialisation..  eg: useRef()

Comment: it didnt work. Got the same error message

Comment: is there any Codesandbox ?

Comment: this will help u..  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66047587/useref-not-working-typeerror-null-is-not-an-object-evaluating-filed2-current

Comment: I went to the post you gave me but I got the same error `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'ref.current.scrollToIndex')`. Do  you know why? I updated the code

Answer (score 0):

Hey initially ref might not be attached in first render, hence you could have done it like this @Nomel

```
 setInterval (() => {
            index = index + 1;
            if(index < totalIndex) {
                ref?.current?.scrollToIndex({animated: true, index: index})
            } else {
                ref?.current?.scrollToIndex({animated: true, index: 0})
                index = 0;
            }
        }, 3000)
```

Anyways your check of not null works fine too :)